# Access 2010 Sum wrong result

Tags: ms-access, sum, int

This is my issue.

First step.
I sum the column HH (alias **SUM_Original_values**) and I get 419. This result is correct.  (see the pic below)

[image]

Second step.
I want take only **INT** values of the HH column's, and I get 417. This result is correct. (see the pic below)

[image]

Third step.
I want to create a column **Global_Int_Sum_HH** (416), but this value is different from **Int_Sum_HH** (417)

[image]

Why the results are differents ?

This is the query

```
SELECT 
 Year, 
 Month, 
 Customer,
 User, 
 Int(Sum(HH)) AS Int_Sum_HH, 

(
SELECT  (int(sum(int(HH)))) AS Global_Int_Sum_HH
FROM T_Att
HAVING (((Year)="2016") AND ((month)="03") AND ((Customer)="FC"));
) AS Global_Int_Sum_HH, 

Customer + Str(Global_Int_Sum_HH) AS [KEY]

FROM T_Att

GROUP BY Year, Month, Customer, User
HAVING (((Year)="2016") AND ((Month)="03") AND ((Customer)="FC"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like there's an inconsistency in your order of operations.

In one instance you `int` the `sum`, and in the second instance you `sum` the `int`.

```
SELECT 
 Year, 
 Month, 
 Customer,
 User, 
 Sum(Int(HH)) AS Int_Sum_HH, 
-- ^ changed order of events to match sub-query
(
-- v removed redundant int()
SELECT  sum(int(HH)) AS Global_Int_Sum_HH
FROM T_Att
HAVING (((Year)="2016") AND ((month)="03") AND ((Customer)="FC"));
) AS Global_Int_Sum_HH, 

Customer + Str(Global_Int_Sum_HH) AS [KEY]

FROM T_Att

GROUP BY Year, Month, Customer, User
HAVING (((Year)="2016") AND ((Month)="03") AND ((Customer)="FC"));
```

The above adjustment will make the "right" answer = `416` for both values.  If you were to change your order of operations to both be `Int(Sum(HH))`, then the `Global_Int_Sum_HH` value would equal `419` and your `Int_Sum_HH` column would be `417` instead.

Comment: Unrelated:  I also recommend you swap your "HAVING" clauses for "WHERE" clauses to increase performance.

Comment: Int(Sum(HH)) is going to give 419 for the global one, not 417.